# NameError: name 'x' is not defined - Python - Django

Tags: python, python-3.x, django, django-views

Tengo un código que me marca un error de una variable indefinida, pero no se porque.

Archivo `models.py`:

```
class Model(models.Model):
    user = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE, null=True)
    valor = models.FloatField(default=10)
    numero = models.FloatField(default=0)
    fecha = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True, null=True)
```

Lo que hace este código es que cuando en lo segundos de la hora actual es 25 guarda en la variable `n0`, la query del Modelo `Model`, después accede al campo numero y le suma un valor, finalmente espera 10 segundos. De igual manera cuando los segundos llegan a 50. TODO BIEN HASTA EL MOMENTO

Archivo `views.py`:

```
import time
from datetime import datetime

def actualizar(request):
    global n0, n1

    if datetime.now().second == 25:
        n0 = Model.objects.all().filter(user=request.user).first()
        n0.valor = n0.numero + 10
        time.sleep(10)

    if datetime.now().second == 50:
        n1 = Model.objects.all().filter(user=request.user).first()
        n1.valor = n1.numero + 20
        time.sleep(20)

    if x == 'activo':
        n0.numero = n0.valor * 1
        n1.numero = n1.valor * 2
        variable_nueva = n0.numero + n1.numero
```

Este código se ejecuta automáticamente por la hora, pero el problema es que aparece el siguiente error:

```
n0.numero = n0.valor * 1

NameError: name 'n0' is not defined
```

El código funciona bien pero no se porque dice que no esta definida si se declaro de manera global, alguna idea amigos, muchas gracias!!!

Y disculpen mi ignorancia :(

Answer (score 1):

LA declaración de una variable global está desaconsejada por que puede dar problemas futuros.

En tu caso, estás intentando declarar una variable local con la palabra `local` delante y eso es incorrecto.

Como estás definiendo una variable dentro de tu método y la consumes en el mismo método, no necesitas para nada que sean globales, igualmente, si decides hacerlas globales, la palabra reservada `local` se utiliza para poder *EDITAR* una variable global previamente definida, pero no para crearlas.

En tu caso, el código quedaría así:

```
import time
from datetime import datetime

def actualizar(request):
    n0 = None
    n1 = None

    if datetime.now().second == 25:
        n0 = Model.objects.all().filter(user=request.user).first()
        n0.valor = n0.numero + 10
        time.sleep(10)

    if datetime.now().second == 50:
        n1 = Model.objects.all().filter(user=request.user).first()
        n1.valor = n1.numero + 20
        time.sleep(20)

    if x == 'activo':
        n0.numero = n0.valor * 1
        n1.numero = n1.valor * 2
        variable_nueva = n0.numero + n1.numero
```

Comment: Ya lo había intentado asi pero me aparece este error viejo:                    TypeError: 'NoneType' object is not iterable

Comment: Ten en cuenta que en el caso de que los dos primeros condicionales sean falsos y el tercero verdadero, estás accediendo a n0 y n1 como si fuesen un objeto del modelo. Debes asignarle un objeto vacío o uno por defecto en lugar de None

Comment: Asi es viejo, muchas gracias!